# Repository as static or non-static class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, repository, clr

Recently I had a discussion with a colleague on whether a repository in a web application (in this case a layer on top of Entity Framework) should be implemented as static or non-static classes.

In this question I'm not interested if one or the other implementation is a better (OOP) design, because that would make the answers subjective.

What I am interested in: Is instantiating and disposing the Entity Framework `DbContext` handled in a different way in the CLR when you compare the static with the non-static class? I am specifically interested in multi-threading issues and memory usage, because this code runs in an MVC web application.

**Edit:** Just to clarify: I'm not interested in the disposal or garbage collection of the repository class, just what happens with the local `context` variable. Is it correct to say that it is carbage collected (or at least marked to be garbage collected) when the method returns?

**Static repository**

```
public static class AccountRepository
{
    public static AccountModel GetAccountById(int accountId)
    {
        using (var context = new EntitiesContext())
        {
            var account = context.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == accountId);
            if (account == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new AccountModel
            {
                Id = account.Id,
                Username = account.Username,
                // etc...
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Non-static repository**

```
public class AccountRepository
{
    public AccountModel GetAccountById(int accountId)
    {
        using (var context = new EntitiesContext())
        {
            var account = context.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == accountId);
            if (account == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new AccountModel
            {
                Id = account.Id,
                Username = account.Username,
                // etc...
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but how does dispose/garbage collection apply to static members? They are never disposed/rid off.

Comment: Static members are stored on high frequency heap and this heap is never approached by GC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between the call of a static method and an instance method is that static methods use one less parameter: the `this` reference which is passed to instance methods. And since the `DbContext` is stored in a local variable in both cases, it's free to be garbage-collected when the method terminates either way. No difference there.

That's still no excuse to use a static repository IMHO. Good vs better design may be subjective. Good vs bad design is not. SoC and SRP aren't either.